# Android. First tab visible under second tab

Tags: android, android-intent

When the second tab is clicked the contents are shown over the content of the first tab. The first tab contents are still visible underneath.
Here's some sample code:

MainActivity.java

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Home tab
    Intent intentHome = new Intent().setClass(this, home.class);
    TabSpec tabSpecHome = tabHost
        .newTabSpec("Home")
        .setIndicator("Home", ressources.getDrawable(R.layout.icon_home))
        .setContent(intentHome);

    // Tools tab
    Intent intentTools = new Intent().setClass(this, tools.class);
    TabSpec tabSpecTools = tabHost
        .newTabSpec("Tools")
        .setIndicator("Tools", ressources.getDrawable(R.layout.icon_tools))
        .setContent(intentTools);
```

ToolsActivity.java

```
public class tools extends Activity {
public static tools self;
private ImageButton imageButton1;
private WebView webView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tools);
    addListenerOnButton1();

public void addListenerOnButton1() {

    imageButton1=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    imageButton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_web);
            webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/tools/calculators.html");
            webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#111111"));
        }

    });

}
```

MainActivity.java uses activity_main.xml and Tools.java uses activity_tools.xml both of which are the same in layout but differ slightly in content.

I tried putting Finish(); at the end of each TabSpec in MainActivity.java but that simply closed the app in the emulator as I suspected it would.

Does anyone have any guidance they could give me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

just remove this line :

webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#111111"));

Comment: No luck with this as the webview background loads in a different xml file. As you can see it's within the onClick function.

Comment: I took the idea of a background colour and found that setting one on the second xml file achieved what I'm after, albeit a dirty fix.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

In Manifest.xml, for activity, use this,

android:noHistory="true"